# Is Russian still alive?

Tags: one-piece

During Dresrosa arc, past of Senõr pink was shown and in that Russian was shown on hospital bed which was around 14-15 years ago. After that it wasn't shown what happened to her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was never revealed but Senor Pink hinted that she passed away. From *One Piece* chapter 775 *Putting all my love into Lucian*

[image]

> Senor Pink : The sky isn't looking great today but.. if I go higher, I just might be able to meet Lucian (Russian)

Unless Russian is on Sky Island it sounds like she passed away

Answer (score 0):

It seems Russian is no more. Here is the article on wikia:-

> It is unknown what happened to her afterwards but, during a short conversation with Franky, Senor Pink has implied that Russian had passed away.

You can read everything about Russian on her [wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Russian)

It clearly says that she is Senor Pink's late wife.